# Wordpress is_single call from plugin class constructor

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi there and happy new year to all.

Lately I'm working on a plugin and I'm stuck on the instantiate step of plugin class.

Here is what I got on main file:

```
<?php

class Filter_Content {

 public function __construct() {
    if( !is_front_page() && !is_home() && !is_single() ) return;
    if( !is_singular( array('post','page') ) ) return;

    add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$this, 'manage_page_content') );
 }


 public function manage_page_content($content) {

    global $post;
    $content_enabled = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_content_enabled', true );

    if( !$content_enabled ) {
        $content = '';
    }

    return $content;
 }

}

$filtercontent = new Filter_Content();

?>
```

However when on constructor method **is_single()** or **is_home()** are called they do not work,
when I move if statements to the method they work ok.
The reason I have to move the if statements to constructor is because there will be more methods which will use those statements.

Comment: What do you mean they "don't work"? What is it doing that constitutes a non-working state? Are you getting errors? Can you show us the errors?

Comment: Hi maiorano84, by that I mean there is no error flown not even a clue. I've got the wp-config.php error debug true. So by not working I mean while I am on a single post it doesn't throw the true value always false.

Comment: It may be a problem with order of operations. Plugins are set up before most everything else, and the global `$wp_query` object may not have been instantiated at this point for you to meaningfully use `is_single()` or `is_singular()`. Try instantiating `Filter_Content` in an `init` action callback.

Comment: Hi maiorano84 really thanks for your time appreciating it.
I tried `add_action( 'init', array( 'Filter_Content', 'init' ) );`
and inserted static method 
`static public function init() {
 $self = __CLASS__;
 new $self; 
}` it is still the same which action should I hook to? I think in init it doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the post type you're viewing when you're looking at a single post? Your `is_singular()` is preventing the filter from executing if you're not looking at a single post of post_type 'post' or 'page', so that might be an issue as well. Try putting `exit('DEBUGGING');` above your filter call and see where the word 'DEBUGGING' shows up (if at all)

Comment: I'm trying that on simple post_type = post nothing else.
I tried to print DEBUG on construct method at the first position `__construct() { echo "DEBUG"; ... }` it prints it ok, when I move it next this if statement: `if( !is_front_page() && !is_home() && !is_single() ) { return; } echo "DEBUG";` it doesn't show up anymore. I think that is what I mean it doesn't work so it doesn't fetch the single as true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try, added notes to the code

```
public function __construct() {

    // Plugins are loaded before themes so you need to fire this when theme template is loading EG wp_head hook
    add_action( 'wp_head', array(&$this, 'filter_check') );
 }


 public function filter_check() {
    if( !is_front_page() && !is_home() && !is_single() ) return;
    if( !is_singular( array('post','page') ) ) return;

    add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$this, 'manage_page_content') );
 }
```

Comment: After I added the title filter too, and used your method now filter to title affects wp_nav content it wipes them all away, its the same concept just as filter to the content. Do you have any idea what may lead to this one ?

Comment: If its the same as your manage_page_content method check if its post type is a post first  if($post->post_type == 'post') { // Your code }

Comment: Didn't help too much. Still the same, I'm going to ask it as a question.